# How to destroy/stop observable interval

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a countdown timer that continues to run after the user has left the page. When the user leaves the page I want to destroy the countdown timer from running or stop it. How can I do this?

countdown.ts

```
public time: number;
public countDown:Observable<any>;
public currentUnix;

constructor() {
    this.currentUnix = moment().unix();
    this.time = moment(1503773977000).unix() - this.currentUnix;
}


ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = Observable.interval(1000)
      .map(res => {
        return this.time = this.time - 1
      })
      .map(res => {

        let timeLeft = moment.duration(res, 'seconds');
        let string: string = '';

        // Days.
        if (timeLeft.days() > 0)
          string += timeLeft.days() + ' Days';

        // Hours.
        if (timeLeft.hours() > 0)
          string += ' ' + timeLeft.hours() + ' Hours';

        // Minutes.
        if (timeLeft.minutes() > 0)
          string += ' ' + timeLeft.minutes() + ' Mins';

        // Seconds.
        string += ' ' + timeLeft.seconds();
        console.log("string", string);
        return string;
      })
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil` operator.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

...

private onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onDestroy$.next();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = Observable.interval(1000)
                               .takeUntil(this.onDestroy$) // <----
                               .map(
...
```

Comment: or `interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe(` in more recent versions of rxjs.

Answer (score 1):

you must have created a subscrtiption based on your `this.countDown`, you can destroy it in `ngOnDestroy`,

Excerpt from [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy),

> Put cleanup logic in ngOnDestroy(), the logic that must run before
> Angular destroys the directive.

```
....
this.subscription = this.countDown.subscribe(...)
...

public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```